# Pre processor: #if comparing two values

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was working on setting up a UART for ATmega168 micro controller. My first code didn't work. While checking on that I came across an header file used in a working program. It uses preprocessor directives.

It was quite confusing for me, so I decided to run it in a c compiler and check outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#ifndef BAUD                          /* if not defined in Makefile... */
#define BAUD  9600                     /* set a safe default baud rate */
#endif

#define BAUD_TOL 2
#define UBRR_VALUE (((F_CPU) + 8UL * (BAUD)) / (16UL * (BAUD)) -1UL)

#if 100 * (F_CPU) > (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) + (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
#define USE_2X 1
#define TEST 1

#elif 100 * (F_CPU) < (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
#define USE_2X 1
#define TEST 11

#else
#define USE_2X 0
#define TEST 111

#endif


int main(void) {

    printf("UBRR_VALUE: %ld\n", UBRR_VALUE);
    printf("USE_2X: %d\n", USE_2X);
    printf("%ld\n", (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL)));
    printf("F_CPU * 100 = %ld\n", (100*F_CPU));
    printf("TEST = %d\n", TEST);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
UBRR_VALUE: 6
USE_2X: 1
105369600
F_CPU * 100 = 100000000
TEST = 11
```

since `100 * F_CPU` is less than `(16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))`, `TEST` is assigned a value of 11.

But it I change the `F_CPU` to `16000000UL`:

```
UBRR_VALUE: 103
USE_2X: 0
1565491200
F_CPU * 100 = 1600000000
TEST = 111
```

Here's also `100 * F_CPU` is less than `(16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))`.

But how come `TEST` is 111?

Edit: *Here's `100 * F_CPU` is greater than `(16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))`

Comment: It should be in the function as seeing the speed compile time is not too useful

Comment: *"Here's also 100 * F_CPU is less than (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL)). "* But it's not: 1600000000 > 1565491200.

Comment: @user694733 Okay mistake noted. But still TEST should be 1, right? Also in the code I posted here, the first `#if` is blurred. Why is that??

Comment: Why should TEST be 1? Comparison `1600000000 > 1629388800` returns `0`, so first branch is not chosen. Are your 2 different calculations in if statements intended (`-` vs `+`)? Also, don't worry about the syntax highlighter issue.

Comment: Okay I understand. I didn't notice the `-` vs `+`

Comment: Design tip: Distribute the calculation over several macros, on several lines. That way you can check what each macro evaluates to. As a bonus, the code also turns readable.

Comment: It's actually a portion of code from `#include<avr/setbaud.h>` header file. I didn't understand how it works that's why I did as above

Answer (score 2):

The macros are expanded as explained below:

For the second case `F_CPU` to `16000000UL` (Larger value)

```
100 * (F_CPU) > (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) + (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
```

evaluates to `0x5f5e1000  > 0x611e8000` which is false

```
100 * (F_CPU) < (16 * ((UBRR_VALUE) + 1)) * (100 * (BAUD) - (BAUD) * (BAUD_TOL))
```

evaluates to `0x5f5e1000  < 0x5d4f8000` which is also false.

Hence the below macros are applicable:

```
#define USE_2X 0
#define TEST 111
```